# CSS: How to select first <td> element in each row?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html fragment:

```
<div id = "fromAddress">
        <table>
            <tr><td id="from">From:</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>Acquirung Bank</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Risk Management</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>100 Bond Street</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>London</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>W1</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td>Fax:</td><td id="fromFax">0207 234567890/</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Tel:</td><td id="fromTel">0207 123456789/</td></tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

My css:

```
#fromAddress td:first-child
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

#fromAddress table table td:fist-child
{
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

How I can make text in first s bold?
So, "From", "Fax", and "Tel" are bold?

Comment: You can use 
tr td:first-child {}

Comment: does not work. It also makes middle table's content bold. I need only "From", "Fax" and " Tel"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#fromAddress > table > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j2mb4f0g/

Chrome at least will add in the `tbody` tag, so you should probably add it to your html to ensure this works in all browsers.

Or to avoid all the '>'s you could do:

```
td:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}

table table td:first-child {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/80v98xuf/

Comment: I tried that, and I got the whole content under inner table bold as well

Comment: look at the fiddle, pretty sure it works (at least in chrome 46)

Comment: When I use div tag reference. It does not work. Take a look at the edit

Comment: you have a typo in your edited post 'fist-child' needs to be 'first-child'